# GCP Dataform Upstream source check

Tags: dataform, google-dataform

Does GCP Dataform provide a mechanism to detect the completion of external upstream source data tasks? For instance, in Airflow, I can check if the source table is ready before executing a DAG. Is there a similar capability in Dataform to verify if the source data is ready? If not, should I rely on Airflow to handle such orchestration and schedule Dataform workflow to run within Airflow?

I searched on Google's documentation and community. I am looking for an answer for my organization.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting Google Cloud community, I learned that I need to orchestrate it using Airflow to handle external source dependencies.